# Is there a way to see which alternate resources were used?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a fair collection of alternative resources in my app, e.g. **values/**, **values-sw480dp/**, **values-large/**, and so forth.

In **values/**, I have themes.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" />
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

In **values-large/**, I have this themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme" />
</resources>
```

And of course, my java code looks something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

But on "large" devices, my alternate theme doesn't seem to be getting picked up.

I can keep doing trial-and-error until I figure out where I'm going wrong, but if there was a way to just *see* from where all the resources were picked up, that would be very useful.

Comment: Practically do you want to know which is the current "values" folder?

Comment: Well, my understanding is that Android will pick and choose each individual value from which individual "values" folder best matches. For example, in my case above, on a large device, **AppTheme** should come from "values-large/" while **MyTheme** should come from "values/". I would like a way to know where each value came from.